# Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker-compose, wsl-2

I'm using WSL2 in Windows to run a Laravel project with docker-compose, everything was working fine, until this error.
When a try to run migrate, this error appear, I know that error is about SSL certificate, but I dont know how to fix.
This project already have a ssl folder with DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem file

[image]

I tried add ssl path in .ini file, it doesnt worked

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following query in the corresponding mysql shell script:
ALTER USER ''@'<host/Ip-address>' REQUIRE <tls_option>; [ tls_option: { SSL | X509 | CIPHER 'cipher' | ISSUER 'issuer' | SUBJECT 'subject' } ]

https://pitstop.manageengine.com/portal/en/kb/articles/how-to-fix-connections-using-insecure-transport-are-prohibited-while-require-secure-transport-on-in-mysql